# "The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call." even with LEAVE

Tags: visual-c++, assembly, x86

When attempting to call a method which is defined in assembly, I'm receiving the error *"The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call."*, using Visual Studio 2012. Looking at other questions, a common factor was the mention that the assembly may not have the `LEAVE` instruction at the end of each label.

I am receiving this error, but with the following code, which does include the `LEAVE` instruction.

```
section .bss
    vs: resb 13 ; 12-byte vendor string + NULL char
    ns: resb 49 ; 48-byte proc. name + NULL char

section .text

global _meta_vendor
global _meta_procname

_meta_vendor:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov eax, 0h
    cpuid
    mov [vs], ebx
    mov [vs + 4], edx
    mov [vs + 8], ecx
    mov byte [vs + 12], 0h
    mov eax, vs
    leave
    ret

_meta_procname:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov eax, 80000002h
    cpuid

    mov [ns], eax
    mov [ns + 4], ebx
    mov [ns + 8], ecx
    mov [ns + 12], edx
    mov eax, 80000003h
    cpuid
    mov [ns + 16], eax
    mov [ns + 20], ebx
    mov [ns + 24], ecx
    mov [ns + 28], edx
    mov eax, 80000004h
    cpuid
    mov [ns + 32], eax
    mov [ns + 36], ebx
    mov [ns + 40], ecx
    mov [ns + 44], edx
    mov byte [ns + 48], 0h
    mov eax, ns
    leave
    ret
```

Function prototypes for those labels are then in a header file which contains only this:

```
#include <cstdint>

extern "C" {
    char* meta_vendor();
    char* meta_procname();
}
```

Any insight as to why I am receiving this error?

Note that, if I click "Continue" on the popup which appears, the expected values do appear.

Comment: Hmm - it looks to me like ESP would be preserved by your code. I do believe you'll need to preserve EBX as well, though.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Adding `push dword ebx` at the start and `pop ebx` and the end removed the runtime check message. Thanks :)

Comment: Visual C++'s own behavior when generating code is to save and restore EBX, EBP, ESI and EDI in each function where they are used (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/984x0h58.aspx)

Comment: Do favor the built-in [instrinsic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hskdteyh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding `push ebx` and `pop ebx` as is shown below:

```
_meta_vendor:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push ebx

    ; code...

    pop ebx
    leave
    ret
```